# Despite using an array for keydown (or keyup) functions my code still refuses to let me move while jumping

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
var map = [];
document.body.onkeydown = document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
  e = e || event; // to deal with IE
  map[e.key] = e.type == 'keydown';
  console.log(map)
  if (map["ArrowLeft"]) {move("left")}
  if (map["ArrowRight"]) {move("right")}
  if (map["Spacebar"] || map[" "]) {jump()};
```

However if i hold down the right arrow key and then press space the character jumps without changing the x pos.
My jumping code is:

```
async function jump() {
  var jh = j;
  var i;
  for (i = jh * 2; i > -Math.abs(jh) * 2 - 0.5; i -= 0.5) {
    rem_rect(70, py, 30, 30)
    py -= i
    rect(70, py, 30, 30)
    await sleep(15)
  }
}
```

My moving code is:

```
async function move(d) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (d === "right") {
      var j;
      for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
        rem_rect(p[i][0], p[i][1], p[i][2], p[i][3]); 
        p[i][0] -= ms / 5;
        rect(p[i][0], p[i][1], p[i][2], p[i][3])
        await sleep(0)
      }
    }
    else if (d === "left") {
      var j;
      for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
        rem_rect(p[i][0], p[i][1], p[i][2], p[i][3]); 
        p[i][0] += ms / 5;
        rect(p[i][0], p[i][1], p[i][2], p[i][3])
        await sleep(0)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome Archie! What is the output for the existing `console` when you press the space bar? Also, have you thought about using `console` inside the `jump` function? It might help you to check whether or not it's called.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both of those things and nothing untoward happens, no errors, and if i check e.key (or the map array) it says exactly what it is supposed to, (just array info (everything looks perfect in the array)), and the jump function is being called - my problem isnt that the jump function isn't being called it is simply that the move function stops (it is not being called unless i stop pressing the arrow key and then press it again, in which case it starts again)

Comment: Learning to use the debugger might be useful for you - it will let you step through the code. Remember also that `await sleep()` will also not delay the function return - that's probably not what you're expecting